# $env:PSModulePath versus %PSModulePath%

Tags: powershell

How comes cmd.exe shows different values for `PSModulePath` than PowerShell does?

**PowerShell:**

```
\\share\user\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
```

**CMD:**

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
```

[image]

Comment: There are [six profile scripts](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx) in Powershell. Maybe one of those modifies the value?

Comment: None of the six profile scripts exists on my system.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variables seems to be modified 'localy' at execution ( changes are not saved to the system ). 
Running cmd from within the powershell console should work as you expect :

```
PS>cmd /c echo %psmodulepath%
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you start up PowerShell it will create a set of environment variables for that session. These can all be found under the $env (ex. $env:PSModulePath). There is a set of default values that go here. These default values are hard corded but you can of course modify those default values by changing it in one of the profile script locations.

As for CMD.exe, whenever it starts up it too will create environment variables, however it's environment variables are pulled from the OS environment.

Go to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced Settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables